# Fullcalendar external event dragg problem

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

Am using fullcalendar external event drag. When I create those external event (that is going to be dragged) by simple code (as written in example scode) creating the div with id external-event its work fine.

But the problem is when am creating those external event through a jquery code,and appending those generated event div to the external-events div.then am not able to dragg those event.

```
var dat;
$(document).ready(function() {


    $.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?", 
            { 
            tags: "cat", 
            tagmode: "any", 
            format: "json" 
            }, 
            function(data) { 
            dat=data;
            $.each(data.items, function(i,item){ 
            //generating the event dynamically.all event are creating but not draggable.
        $('#external-events').append("<div class='external-event'>ghgh</div>");

           }); 
    )};
```

Html code

```
 <div id='external-events'> <h4>Draggable Events</h4> <p> <input
 type='checkbox' id='drop-remove' /> <label for='drop-remove'>remove
 after drop</label> </p> </div>
```

Comment: Can you please post your code?(also add a comment below this post so that i know you have posted your code! :))

Comment: @Nicola i have attached the code please take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue by myself,
Only thig is that thos dynamically created div is generating letter after those event are register/biend with jquery draggable.Only thing i need to do is ,we need to put the dynamically generated div code on the event regestering part before.

Comment: after i tryed it with the generating simple dynamic div and register it it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(data.items, function(i,item){ 
//generating the event dynamically.all event are creating but not draggable.
    $('#external-events').append("<div class='external-event'>ghgh</div>");
    $('#external-events div.external-event').draggable({
        zIndex: 999,
        revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
        revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the dra
    });
});
```

Try this! It will make external dynamic data draggable! :)